# Looping through URLs using Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I'm a total laymen here when it comes to automation and I'm trying to figure out how to perform what I think is a pretty basic function. Essentially, I have a few thousand items on a website that I want to delete. The way I'd like to do so is basically as follows:

1. Go to URL https://website.com/[itemnumber]
2. Select the delete button (UI element)
3. Increment [itemnumber] and delete the next one
4. If that [itemnumber] doesn't exist (404 error), increment and go to the next one

Again, complete laymen. I don't really know JS and the only thing I have running right now that I think could lead me to a solution is Selenium, but if there's a better way to perform this I'm totally open. Thanks!

Comment: Better to remove items sending HTTP requests directly without opening it in UI, because it will take really a long time to open several thousand of items. You can check at what url request is send when you click "delete" button and just iterate same request

Comment: If you familiar with `Python`, you might try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) lib to send `HTTP` request to delete each item in a loop

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using loop. For Java, below code might give you an idea.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //For example i am taking item number upto 10
    int itemnumbber = 10;
    for(int i = 0;i<=itemnumbber;i++)
    {
        String url = "https://website.com/["+i+"]";
        driver.navigate().to(url);

        //Checks the delete element. If if exists click it
        if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("DELETEXPATH")).size()>0)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("DELETEXPATH")).click();
        }
    }
```

Modify the itemnumber count as per the requirement. Hope this helps you. Thanks.